# postgreSQL - SELECT all rows where an id only differs by one

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I would like to return all fields where given name is equal, but an id only differs by one(1) on psql 9.5.6.

So with the input:

```
NAME     | ID
______________
Harry    | 12
Harry    | 13
Steven   | 14
Steven   | 16
Goldberg | 21
```

The output should be:

```
   Harry
```

Comment: what if there are 3 or more id's per name and only some differs by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Select name  from table
       group by name having 
      max(id)- min(id)=1;
```

> I think you asked id difference by each name as group by seeing the output. Can try the above.

Comment: Yes, that worked and was what I was trying to express, sorry for the bad english.
Have this website that gives you Pokemon-Colorpalletes as a small thank you: http://pokepalettes.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` or `lag()`:

```
select t.name
from (select t.*,
             lag(id) over (partition by name order by id) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t
where prev_id = id - 1;
```